# AJAX display only "name" from array

Tags: php, ajax

I want to display only the field name but only can get the full array...
I tryed result.name result['name'] and never accomplish nothing
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QACJ1.png)

HTML File

```
 <script>
        $("select").change(function () {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "testephp.php", //Relative or absolute path to response.php file
                datatype:'json',
                data: {name: $("select").val()},
                success: function (result) {

                   $(".container").html(result);

                }
            });
            //console.log(value);
        });

    </script>
```

PHP File

```
$conn = DataBase::getDB();
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("select * from user where name=:name");
    $stmt->execute(array(':name' => $_POST['name']));
    $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    echo json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make a small change here:

It is not

```
datatype:'json'
```

It is: T

```
dataType:'json'
    ^
```

See the [manual](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/): **dataType** (default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html))

Then you can use either:

```
$(".container").html(result.name);
```

or

```
$(".container").html(result['name']);
```

to display the result. Hope this helps!

Comment: `datatype` is just fine.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use foreach in jquery. So the syntax is like:

```
$(result).each(function(key, value){
    var name = value.name;
    var surname = value.surname
    //similarly access all contents in your array.
});
```